# Inserting values into a Hash for YAML dump

Tags: ruby, hash, yaml, loops

I'm creating a hash that will eventually be dumped on disk in YAML, but I need to capture multiple values stored in a file on disk and insert them into a hash.  I can successfully create a variable with comma separated values, but I need to insert those values into a my "classes" key:

```
variable_values = "class1,class2,class3"
```

Ultimately, I need to get them into my test hash so it simulates something like this:

```
test_hash = {'Classes' => ['class1', 'class2', 'class3']}
```

Finally, I can output them to yaml so it looks like this:

```
--- 
classes: 
- class1
- class2
- class3
```

What's the best way to iterate through the values and insert them into the hash? Thanks for any help you can offer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd probably want something like:

```
test_hash = {'Classes' => variable_values.split(',')}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed - makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 1):

If you're wanting to serialize Ruby Classes (I'm not able to tell for sure), you'll probably want the following code (courtesy of [opensoul.org](http://opensoul.org/2010/5/3/the-quest-for-the-holy-object-serialization-format), and as used in the [Small Eigen Collider](https://github.com/agrimm/small_eigen_collider/blob/master/lib/small_eigen_collider/serialization.rb))

```
class Module
  yaml_as "tag:ruby.yaml.org,2002:module"

  def Module.yaml_new( klass, tag, val )
    if String === val
      val.split(/::/).inject(Object) {|m, n| m.const_get(n)}
    else
      raise YAML::TypeError, "Invalid Module: " + val.inspect
    end
  end

  def to_yaml( opts = {} )
    YAML::quick_emit( nil, opts ) { |out|
      out.scalar( "tag:ruby.yaml.org,2002:module", self.name, :plain )
    }
  end
end

class Class
  yaml_as "tag:ruby.yaml.org,2002:class"

  def Class.yaml_new( klass, tag, val )
    if String === val
      val.split(/::/).inject(Object) {|m, n| m.const_get(n)}
    else
      raise YAML::TypeError, "Invalid Class: " + val.inspect
    end
  end

  def to_yaml( opts = {} )
    YAML::quick_emit( nil, opts ) { |out|
      out.scalar( "tag:ruby.yaml.org,2002:class", self.name, :plain )
    }
  end
end
```

The code currently throws an exception if you try to serialize/deserialize anonymous classes (something I could fix but don't need to), and apart from that it works well for me.